# two columns in two rows

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have this table:

```
 ID     Value         
 -----------------    
  3       A1                    
  4       A2                    
  8       A20                 
  10      A10
```

I have to create only two rows with the name of the columns at the beginning, I think using the pivot, but I don't know how to do it:

```
 ID        3    4    8    10  
 -----------------------------------    
 Value     A1   A2  A20   A10
```

Comment: Welcome to **Database Administrators**. Please, check the [How do I ask a good question?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) instructions to avoid being downvoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 'Value' AS ID, [3], [4], [8], [10]  
FROM test
PIVOT ( MAX(value)  
        FOR id IN ([3], [4], [8], [10])  
      ) AS PivotTable;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=cab0bf797116e6c69784772cbd04c5a9)